# How do i create a typescript interface for following response data

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create a  typescript interface for the following response data only for "hits" key and its nested data as shown in the image. Please somebody help me.

[Image Link with response data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCOZL.png)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple project (with static data structures):

Paste your demo json in http://json2ts.com/  and you will get some typescript interfaces.

There are a lot of other sites that will do this, [json-to-typescript](https://transform.tools/json-to-typescript), [MakeTypes](https://jvilk.com/MakeTypes/), [quicktype.io](https://quicktype.io/typescript/)

It's import to have  good demo data. A lot of null values causes a lot of 'any' types.